# Python3 how to syncronize a manager Dict between two Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.4

I am working on a TestSuite app based on Python. In this application I have a running report multiprocessing thread which generate a html report of all the test cases execute by the main program.

The main program it self is multi threaded although using the Normal threading module.

Now this report writer thread act like a server and each test case thread started by the main application can ask for an interface to this writer (IFW).

Communicating from the IFW to the writer just use a single `Queue()`. However it is also possible for each of the IFW's to ask for a status form the writer and here is where it gets tricky because this data is IFW ID specific.

It is not possible to just use Queues because of the IFW dynamic behavior, so I used a manager to create a proxy Queue however this cause a lot of problems for me (created a new manager instance for each interface). So now I'm trying with the `manager().dict()` method. However I cannot figure out how to synchronize between the to threads. Here is my code from the IFW:

```
  def getCurrentTestInfo(self):
    self._UpdateQueue.put_nowait(WriterCtrlCmd(self.WriterIfId, 'get_current_test_info'))
    while self.WriterIfId not in self._RequestDict:
      pass
    res = self._RequestDict[self.WriterIfId]
    del self._RequestDict[self.WriterIfId]
    return res
```

What happens here is that the IFW sends a request cmd to the writer and the writer then returns the test infomation. Along with this request cmd is there a specific IFW ID, this ID is unique.

I know at this point that the entry does not exist in the `dict()` so I wait for the entry to show up using a "poll" :) and then I read the data. However everyone can see the potential problem in this code.

Is there a way to somehow wait for the dict to be updated by means of the manager ? maybe an event or condition ? Although I would like something linked to the dict() method it self

NOTE there is a period of processing time from the put command until the dict have been updated. so I cannot use `Queue.put()` instead of `Queue.put_nowait()`

Comment: You've actually already mentioned the primitive that you need: `threading.Event.`. Alternatively, a complete restructuring using the new executors and future objects from `concurrent.futures` could make this simpler. You post the request to perform an operation to an executor and wait on the future for it to finish.

Comment: Ok. I will look into it. I am looking for something which is bound to the Manager object so i know when i set one and then the other it follows through to the other end in that order.

Comment: An executor with a single thread / process will probably result in the desired behavior.